# How to store output of .bat FIND in a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm writing a batch file to find out if certain programs are currently running. Here is my code so far:

```
for %%x in ("notepad++.exe" "eclipse.exe") do ( 
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %%x" | find /I /C %%x
)
```

What I would like to be able to do is store the result from the "tasklist" line (which should be a number that is greater than or equal to 0) in a variable.

I guess I am really asking: is it possible to capture this output; and, if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `FOR /F`:

```
for %%x in ("notepad++.exe" "eclipse.exe") do ( 
  for /f %%c in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %%x" ^| find /I /C %%x') do echo %%c
)
```

Put the command whose output you want to capture inside single quotes and escape any characters with special meaning in the shell, such as the pipe, with the shell escape character `^`.

Don't forget to look at `FOR /?` for additional options when using `FOR /F`.

Comment: @npocmaka: The question does not ask specifically about storing the result. In addition, this particular example is expected to produce up to two lines of output, and it is very unobvious how exactly one would want to store both of them in one or more variable(s). So instead of making specific suggestions based on wild guesses I just demonstrated how you get the output.

Comment: It worked quite well. I have a few other problems I need to iron out, but this took care of the biggest problem I've been having.

Thanks!

Comment: To be fair, the title does say it was to be in a variable. :)